# Questions about CCD sensors and low temperatures?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, space, low-temperature-physics

The dynamic range of a CCD sensor increases at low temp, they say. What does this mean, and why does it happen?

Near saturation a CCD sensor begins to exhibit non-linear characteristics. Is this in any way affected by low temperatures? How?

Generally, are CCD-sensors in space probes heated, or are they just a few degrees above absolute zero?

I'm asking this because I'm interested in the camera on the Dawn space probe. It had a chip called TH788X, that was used on Dawn and in other space probes and also in security cameras.

Comment: More perhaps that noise is reduced so signal-to-noise gets better

Comment: Most components are made to work within certain temperature ranges. Semiconductors tend to simply not work at $T=0$ and will need some heating. However, to explain why would require a whole lot of university modules.